# How to set the font of TextInputEditText in theme.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-styles

I want to apply the `font` to multiple `TextInputEditTexts` in common using style.

However, there is `TextInputLayout` in `parent`, but `TextInputEditText` cannot be found.
(Even if the font is applied to `TextInputLayout`, the font of `TextInputEditText` does not change).

Can't TextInputEditText be inherited?

Should I just extend EditText to define the style?

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 
    <style name="SignInEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">245dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">488dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_pwd"
        style="@style/LogInEditTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:hint="PWD"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_id">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `TextInputEditText`, it appears that the "parent" style you're looking for is named `Widget.Design.TextInputEditText`:

```
ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(
    context,
    attrs,
    R.styleable.TextInputEditText,
    defStyleAttr,
    R.style.Widget_Design_TextInputEditText); // <--- this style
```

Alternatively, you could leverage the "default style attribute":

```
public TextInputEditText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
```

You would do this by creating a style of your choice, and then referencing that in your activity's theme:

```
<style name="YourActivityTheme">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/YourEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YourEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:minWidth">245dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">488dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't understand it well, but then, is there no way to inherit `TextInputEditText style` from `theme.xml`?